# "Contract section within try block" error for context connection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-contracts

I have written this snippet and its contract:

```
[Pure]
public string getLevelName()
{
    using (var c = new myContext())
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() == c.Level.FirstOrDefault(i => i.levelId == this.levelId).name);
        return c.Level.FirstOrDefault(i => i.levelId == this.levelId).name;
    }

}
```

but I get this error for contract:

> Contract section within try block.

How can I avoid this error for this sort of contract for a method?

Comment: You should put all Contract.Requires() and Contract.Ensures() at the start of the method. If you cannot, then it's not something that's of use to the caller anyway - the assertion should be checkable using only the data passed to the method or by using public static methods. (Your example looks more like something that should be in a unit test.)

Comment: You shouldn't use contracts in this way - they are meant to be for validating the state of calls _to_ the method, usually parameters, not the interaction of what the method is _calling_.

Comment: @Rhumborl I simply check that method works properly or not (virtually!)!

Comment: @Rhumborl is right about this particular contract, but people may need a solution to the general case.  However, if you need to make sure the method works properly, you should use a unit test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling another method,

```
public string getLevelName()
{
    using (var c = new myContext())
    {
       return getLevelNameFrom(c);
    }

}

public string getLevelNameFrom(MyContext c)
{
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() == c.Level.FirstOrDefault(i => i.levelId == this.levelId).name);
        return c.Level.FirstOrDefault(i => i.levelId == this.levelId).name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put all `Contract.Ensures` calls at the start of the method.  The using statement is shorthand for a try finally block (the compiler extrapolates this for you).

Your code:

```
using (var c = new myContext())
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() == c.Level.FirstOrDefault(i => i.levelId == this.levelId).name);
    return c.Level.FirstOrDefault(i => i.levelId == this.levelId).name;
}
```

Turns into:

```
var c = new myContext();
try{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() == c.Level.FirstOrDefault(i => i.levelId == this.levelId).name);
}
finally
{
    if (c != null)
        ((IDisposable)c).Dispose();
}
```

So essentially you are putting a Contract.Ensures call into a try block (just like the error is telling you).  See this msdn article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412865.aspx in particular:

> This method call must be at the beginning of a method or property, before any other code.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412865.aspx)

> This method call must be at the beginning of a method or property,
>   before any other code.

In you sample

```
using (var c = new myContext())
```

would be transformed be compiler to

```
try 
{
  c = new myContext();
  Contract.Ensures ...
}
finally
{
   c.Dispose();
}
```

To avoid this use another private method and pass your context there